# Automatically inputting "E" so many columns over from "P"

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a growing calendar, where each variety has a different growing length.
I would like to create a VBA? which will automatically input "E" (Expected Harvest) into the cell so many columns to the right depending on the variety from "P" (Planted)
The "P" would be manually inputted.
And "H" would be manually inputted when the plant has been Harvested.

Once it has been Harvested, I would like that row to go to the bottom.
So all the expected plants to be harvested, are at the top.

What it would look like ideally
[image: What it would look like ideally]

[image: Sheet 2]

I know the end result, getting there, need help

Comment: What specific problem did you run into with your attempt?

Comment: In 2nd table, is `Variety` an unique list? Is `Variety` a key to determine the location of `E`?

Comment: Yes, Variety is a unique list and is key to where E goes after the P.
The first sheet has just been manually inputted so I know what im after when I have been tryign to get it to work.

Comment: Why not use a formula? Why VBA?

Comment: Doesn't have to be VBA, just have not come across a formula that would do it

Answer (score 0):

Write the code into the module of the first sheet, users' input tiggers the Change event to insert `E`.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Row > 2 And .Column > 5 And UCase(.Value) = "P" Then
                ' Update sheet name as need, loading the 2nd table
                arr = Sheets("Sheet2").[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
                For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i, 4) = Me.Cells(.Row, 2) Then
                        If .Column + arr(i, 5) <= Me.Columns.Count Then
                            Application.EnableEvents = False
                            .Offset(0, arr(i, 5)).Value = "E"
                            .Offset(0, arr(i, 5)).Interior.Color = 12574926
                            Application.EnableEvents = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

btw, the location of `E` in last row on OP seems incorrect. `CO` and `GO` have the same growing days.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just added a "Harv." column to enter the day of harvest and then used this formula:

```
=IF(H$2=$F3,"H",IF(H$2-1=VLOOKUP($B3,GrowingDaysTable[#All],2,FALSE),"E",""))
```

Or, in R1C1:

```
=IF(R2C=RC6,"H",IF(R2C-1=VLOOKUP(RC2,GrowingDaysTable[#All],2,FALSE),"E",""))
```

Couple that with conditional formatting I get this:

[image: xlsx]